# Stripe error "create token with card(_:completion:) is unavailable"

Tags: swift

In this line, the error was Display. Can someone tell me what mistake was made?

```
 Stripe.createTokenWithCard(card, completion: { (token: STPToken!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
        self.handleToken(token)
```

Comment: Can you place your code in your question please?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had the same problem after updating Stripe in pods recently. That method is deprecated. Instead, you can use the following code:

```
STPAPIClient.sharedClient().createTokenWithCard(card, completion: { (token: STPToken!, error: NSError!) -> Void in     
})
```

It takes the same parameters.

Update

Thanks to @Christine and @Keyhole150

This function in Stripe API has now be changed to

```
STPAPIClient.sharedClient().createTokenWithCard(card, completion: { (token: STPToken?, error: NSError?) -> Void in     
})
```

Comment: Wow thanks a lot, was searching for quite some time because I was getting this error. Thanks again!

Answer (score 4):

Thanks, @Shali! Your tip is helpful.

For those who are beginners like me, you might still get an error. In case you experience an error indicating either an extra argument in call before adding `sharedClient()` or how `createTokenWithCard` cannot be invoked after `sharedClient()` is added, it helps to make the completion arguments optional (as in `STPToken?` and `NSError?`).

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by Christine, the method now uses Optionals so it looks like the following:

```
    STPAPIClient.sharedClient().createTokenWithCard(card, completion: { (token: STPToken?, error: NSError?) -> Void in     
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

**For objective-c using latest stripe pod**

```
#import "Stripe.h"

STPCardParams *cardParams = [[STPCardParams alloc] init];
cardParams.number = @"4242424242424242";
cardParams.expMonth = 10;
cardParams.expYear = 2018;
cardParams.cvc = @"123";

[[STPAPIClient sharedClient] createTokenWithCard:cardParams completion:^(STPToken *token, NSError *error) {
    if (token == nil || error != nil) {
        // Present error to user...
        NSLog(@"%@",error.description);
        return;
    }

NSLog(@"token.tokenId :: %@",token.tokenId);

}];
```