# Implementing Stripe with iPhone

Tags: ios, objective-c, in-app-purchase, stripe-payments

I'm trying to integrate Stripe with ios. I'm following [this](https://stripe.com/docs/mobile/ios) guide.

I'm getting stuck [here](https://stripe.com/docs/mobile/ios#stpcard-token) at 'Using an STPCard'.

When I start typing this `[Stripe createTokenWithCard:card...` Xcodes 'Intelligent code completion' puts a red line through it (kinda like when something is depricated).

Here is the code.

```
[Stripe createTokenWithCard:card completion:^(STPToken *token, NSError *error) {
    if (error) {
      [self handleError:error];
    } else {
      [self createBackendChargeWithToken:token];
    }
  }];
```

Comment: Did you declare `handleError:` in the current class?

Comment: no. I guess Stripe want's us to create the handleError class.

Comment: @IanMacDonald I'm gonna edit the question, and take out the question about 'handleError'.

Comment: Just found an answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28082195/stripe-error-create-token-with-card-completion-is-unavailable,  but its in swift, and I need it in objective c

Comment: Does `[[STPAPIClient sharedClient] createTokenWithCard:card completion:completion]` work for you?

Comment: Yah!! Thanks! You should post it as an answer so I can give it the accepted answer!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Their API has been updated since the tutorial that you are using.

The new access method for this is:

```
[[STPAPIClient sharedClient] createTokenWithCard:card completion:completion]
```